# Swift - checking type of a generic class

Tags: swift, generics, types

I am having a Swift generic class as follows:

```
class List<T> {
    var value: T
    var next: List<T>?
    ...
}
```

I would like to check for some object if it is an instance of this class, no matter what the type T is. For example, if I'm having:

```
let a = List<Int>(2, 3)
let b = List<Any>(5, List<String>("a", "b"))
let c = "something which is not a list"
```

I would like the procedure (or the code snippet) to return true for `a` and `b`, and false for `c`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the solutions can be to use a protocol for your generic `List`:

```
protocol AnyList {}

class List<T>: AnyList {
    var value: T
    var next: List<T>?
    ...
}

func isList<T>(_ object: T) -> Bool {
    object is AnyList
}

let a = List<Int>(value: 2)
let b = "something which is not a list"

print(isList(a)) // true
print(isList(b)) // false
```

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` is a generic type, and `List<Int>` and `List<String>` are concrete types, but `List` alone is not a type, it's just an identifier.

So, it's meaningless to say that 2 things are both a `List`. Furthermore, `List<Int>` and `List<String>`, for example, are as different from each other as some `Foo` and `Bar`.

If you want to reason about lists you'd need something common between these two, which is a protocol or a base class. However, because your list has a generic element type, there's almost nothing that is actually common between any two lists with different elements, aside from maybe functions like `count` or `print`.

So you could do something like this (as correctly suggested in another answer)

```
protocol AnyList {
   func count() -> Int
   func print() -> Void
   // but, var value: T wouldn't work
}

class List<T>: AnyList {
  ...
}
```

But you can see that a common `AnyList` is of limited use compared to what a list does.

At the end, you need to ask yourself what you want to do next with any kind of "list", having concluded that something like `List<Int>` and `List<String>` are both lists, but knowing nothing about their concrete value types.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to flatten the list at the end, so I would like to distinguish if, for example, I am having a `List<List<Int>>(List<Int>(2, 3), List<Int>(4, 5))` when I'm iterating through the list I'd like to see that each element is indeed another list so I have to flatten that element as well, while in the case I have `List<Int>(2, 3)`, I can just deduce that the underlying type is Int hence no further flattening can be done.

Comment: So, your original top level list is a list of lists? Seems odd to me, but I guess I don't know what you are trying to achieve, so if it works for you, great :)